# How to re populate drop-down field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please check my code carefully:

***JavaScript***

```
var myColor = 'blue'; //This is dynamic

var str1 = 'Color: <select name="chat_color" id="chat_color"><option value="red">Red</option><option value="green">Green</option><option value="blue">Blue</option><option value="yellow">Yellow</option></select>\n\
\n\
 <input type="submit" class="loginbox-btn" value=" Save Color ">';

$('#example').html(str1);
```

Above JavaScript code my color currently is `blue` so I want to show html within `example` div id with select `Blue` color in the drop-down option.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .val() on select element:

```js
var myColor = 'blue'; //This is dynamic

var str1 = 'Color: <select name="chat_color" id="chat_color"><option value="red">Red</option><option value="green">Green</option><option value="blue">Blue</option><option value="yellow">Yellow</option></select>\n\
\n\
 <input type="submit" class="loginbox-btn" value=" Save Color ">';

$('#example').html(str1).find('#chat_color').val(myColor);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the color and set the HTML attribute selected="selected"

```
    var myColor = 'blue'; //This is dynamic

    var str1 = 'Color: <select name="chat_color" id="chat_color"><option value="red"'+(myColor == 'red'?' selected="selected"':'')+'>Red</option><option value="green"'+(myColor == 'green'?' selected="selected"':'')+'>Green</option><option value="blue"'+(myColor == 'blue'?' selected="selected"':'')+'>Blue</option><option value="yellow"'+(myColor == 'yellow'?' selected="selected"':'')+'>Yellow</option></select><input type="submit" class="loginbox-btn" value=" Save Color ">';

    $('#example').html(str1);
```

Comment: No problem, but I recommend using the answer of @R4nc 1d

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 ......//Rest of your code
 $('#example').html(str1);
 $('#chat_color').val(myColor); //Value of select is myColor
```

Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2r3txe24/1/).**

Answer (score 0):

You can find the right element, and make it selected,  as follows:

```
$("input[value=" + myColor + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.val( value )` ***Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.***

So all you need to-do is find the Dropdownbox after you have added it into the `<div id='example'></div>`

```
$('#example').html(str1);
$("#chat_color").val(myColor);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1smebq6/)